# Permissão de arquivos no Linux

Tags: linux, sistema-de-arquivos, permissões

Olá, minha dúvida não é exatamente a respeito de questões de programação, mas sim a respeito do Linux e suas permissões de acesso de arquivos.

Recentemente, tive que mudar as permissões de dois arquivos do sistema em diretórios que normalmente oferecem acesso de somente leitura (aparentemente) para seus arquivos. Usei o chmod 777 para poder fazer a edição e agora gostaria de retornar ao padrão dos arquivos de sistema do linux. Entretanto, não consigo encontrar nenhum lugar especificando isso. Alguém saberia me informar isso? Obrigado.

Comment: Poderia esclarecer sua pergunta? Acho que tem uma pergunta aí dentro, mas não estou conseguindo entender 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Logue com o mesmo usuário com o qual você fez todas as ações descritas.

Execute o comando `umask` para descobrir as permissões padrão do seu usuário. O comando vai lhe retornar um número em base octal, tipo `0002` (ignore o primeiro `0`, porque, à exemplo do `0x` que precede todo número em base hexadecimal, o primeiro `0` é irrelevante).

Se os arquivos que você modificou **não** são diretórios, então subtraia o valor obtido com o comando `umask` de `666`, e utilize o valor resultante em um novo comando `chmod` a ser executado sobre os arquivos. Exemplo:

```
$ umask
Resultado: "0002"
666 - 002 = 664

$ chmod 664 NOME_DO_ARQUIVO
```

Mas se os arquivos modificados são diretórios, substitua o `666` nos cálculos acima por `777`.

**Explicação do que aconteceu ali encima**

As permissões em um sistema Unix/Linux são definidas pela seguinte sequência de caractéres:

```
_rwxrwxrwx 1 dono:grupo
```

O `_` no começo você pode ignorar para seu problema (é uma flag de permissões especiais, podendo classificar o arquivo com permissões especiais de **arquivo**, **diretório** ou **nenhuma permissão especial**)

Em seguida existem 3 conjuntos de `rwx` (onde `r` representa permissão de leitura, `w` permissão de escrita, e `x` de execução). O primeiro conjunto exibe as permissões do usuário dono do arquivo (quem criou o arquivo), o segundo conjunto são as permissões do grupo ao qual o arquivo pertence (um grupo pode conter mais de um usuário), e o último conjunto de permisssões são as permissões para todos os outros usuários do sistema.

`dono:grupo` representa a qual usuário e grupo o arquivo pertence.

Então um arquivo com as seguintes permissões `_rw_rw_r_` pode ser Lido e Escrito pelo dono do arquivo e pelos usuários pertencentes ao grupo do arquivo. Os outros usuários podem apenas Ler o arquivo.

Para mudar as permissões de um arquivo você utiliza o comando `chmod` seguido de 3 números representando, em ordem, as permissões para Dono, Grupo, Outros Usuários. Os números podem ser:

- 4 para Leitura
- 2 para Escrita
- 1 para Execução
- qualquer soma dos anteriores (e.g. 4 + 2 = 6, representa permissão de Leitura + Escrita)

Por isso que seu comando `chmod 777` liberou tudo que queria fazer no arquivo, porque 7 = 6 + 2 + 1, ou seja, permissão de Leitura, Escrita e Execução pro dono, grupo e outros usuários do sistema.

Então, agora você já sabe como definir a permissão de arquivos ou diretórios da forma que quiser, mas e quanto à

> e agora gostaria de retornar ao padrão dos arquivos de sistema do linux.

Para isso você pode utilizar o comando `umask`. Ele retorna quais permissões **não** devem ser definidas em todos os arquivos e diretórios criados pelo usuário atual no sistema. Para usuários padrão (não root), o valor padrão é de `0002` (ignore o primeiro `0` que apenas indica que o número está em base octal), enquanto que para usuários root o padrão é de `0022`.

Então para definir as permissões de um arquivo normal, subtraia o valor retornado por `umask` de `666` e utilize esse novo valor no comando `chmod`.

E para definiar permissões de diretórios, subtraia o `umask` de `777`.

**Referências**

https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions
http://www.tutonics.com/2012/12/linux-file-permissions-chmod-umask.html

Comment: Obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza o comando

```
ls -lah
```

Ela vai te mostrar as permissões dos arquivos.

Veja este link: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Entendendo-as-permissoes-de-arquivos-no-Linux

Acredito que o padrão seja 644...